# How to position options of select box

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-material

I have a select box below a header. Header is fixed header at the top of the page. When I click on it and when first option is selected it shows nicely.(could not add more link as I do not have much reputation)

Lets say I selected second option. Now when I click on the select box to change option the top part of option list goes behind the fixed headed.

[top part behind fixed header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SHTJ.png)

What css style should I  use to display the option list properly.

I am using bootstrap 3 and select box is from angular material.

Right now I am using a very high z-index value to show it.

Below is code for header

```
<header id="header" class="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/#/dashboard" ng-if="location.path() != '/welcome'"><h3>RentedRoofs</h3></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#login" du-smooth-scroll ng-if="location.path() == '/welcome'"><h3>RentedRoofs</h3></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-show="location.path() != '/welcome'">
            <li ng-class="{active: location.path() == '/dashboard'}">
                <a href="/#/dashboard">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-show="location.path() == '/welcome'">
            <li>
                <a  href="#login" du-smooth-scroll>Login</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#howItWorks" du-smooth-scroll>Know How</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact" du-smooth-scroll>Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-show="location.path() != '/welcome'">
            <li ng-click="logout()">
                <a > Logout </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Code of select box

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <md-input-container ng-if="owner.allProperties.length > 1" ng-class="{'big-centered': !owner.selectedProperty}">
                <md-select placeholder="Select Property To View Details" ng-model="owner.selectedProperty">
                    <md-option ng-repeat="property in owner.allProperties" ng-value="property">
                        {{getAddressString(property.address)}}
                    </md-option>
                </md-select>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css class

```
.big-centered{
font-size: 1.7em;
margin-top: 20%;
}
```

To make it more clear I have created the codepen demo[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZYRbG)
To produce the problem. Select state. Then choose AZ. Then again click on select box Now you will see AL hidden.

Comment: We can't say anything without seeing the code.

Comment: I have added it now @Mr Lister.  Please tell me if anything else is needed

Answer (score 0):

Honestly you shouldn't mix bootstrap and angular material. Angular Material has a toolbar directive in it already that will prevent this from happening.

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" class="md-padding selectdemoBasicUsage" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div>
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h2>Toolbar things</h2>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content>
      <div layout="row">
      <md-input-container>
        <label>State</label>
        <md-select ng-model="ctrl.userState">
          <md-option ng-repeat="state in ctrl.states" value="{{state.abbrev}}">
            {{state.abbrev}}
          </md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
    </md-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ywepga